# Bluemix IOS version crashes on XCODE

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

I installed the demo app (Hellotodo) according to instructions on Github. The client app, run on IOS 9 XCODE 7.2, crashes due to InvalidRoute.

I copied the route from the Mobile Options link on the Bluemix Dashboard of my backend app.

```
IMFClient *imfClient = [IMFClient sharedInstance];
    [imfClient initializeWithBackendRoute:@"<https://MobileHost.mybluemix.net>" backendGUID:@"<1b9ec584-1d9f-48bd-a8bb-d31eccb971f9>"];
```

> 2016-09-25 11:26:09.278 helloTodo[1912:2789776] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'InvalidURLException', reason: 'Invalid
>   applicationRoute: https://MobileHost.mybluemix.net'
>   *** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

You left the greater/less than signs ( `<` and `>` ) in the Backend route and GUID, so they are invalid.

You should replace them like this:

```
IMFClient *imfClient = [IMFClient sharedInstance];
    [imfClient initializeWithBackendRoute:@"https://MobileHost.mybluemix.net" backendGUID:@"1b9ec584-1d9f-48bd-a8bb-d31eccb971f9"];
```